# Inter-arrival time of negative binomial distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, interarrival-time

In order to simulate a process I considered two options:

1. number of items received follows a Poisson distribution *λ*
2. number of items received follows a Negative Binomial distribution (*r*,*p*): following Wikipedia definition

I'd like to model both scenarios, customizing the inter-arrival time of the items.

For option 1 (Poisson) the inter-arrival time follows an exponential distribution of *λ*.

Which distribution (and which is the relation between parameters) should I use?

Thank you very much :)

EDIT: Sorry if I didn't explain myself well. Having a Negative Binomial distribution to model the number of arrivals, I'd like to know if the inter-arrival time of arrivals follows a specific distribution. (the same way as a Poisson distribution is related to an exponential distribution, having both the same parameter *λ*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of processes that are not Poisson?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37589/examples-of-processes-that-are-not-poisson)

Comment: Why is that a duplicate?

Comment: I don't understand it either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying process is called the *Bernoulli* process with parameter
$p$ in which the
*inter-arrival* time is integer-valued, and has a *geometric* distribution
with parameter $p$. The number of arrivals in the time interval
$(0,n]$ is a *binomial* random variable with parameters $(n,p)$. The time of the $n$-th arrival is a negative binomial random varianble with
parameters $(n,p)$. Note that the *arrival* rate is $p$: on $n$ trials
($n$ very large),
we expect to see roughly $np$ arrivals.